# How do I check version of R language installed on my system?

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed r language and r studio on my Fedora-20 system few months back. After that I got busy and now coming back to it. I wanted to know what my R version is, and I am unable to find any help on it. Is there any command/function I can use to find out version of r and rstudio?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15983069/2563804

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There is a `version` command (not function) in R that provide a fulfilling overview on R environment and version:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.1                         
year           2015                        
month          06                          
day            18                          
svn rev        68531                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
nickname       World-Famous Astronaut
```

Comment: Its not really a "command" (R doesn't have those) its an object with class "simple.list", and the print method for "simple.list" is activated when you type its name and its printed as you show. You can get bits out of it such as `version$platform` as with any R list.

Answer (score 24):

Type `R --version` at the linux command line.

Comment: Note: it has to be capital R.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `getRversion()` or `R.Version()$version.string` to show info under R, if you want to check R version from Ubuntu you need to type:

```
dpkg -s r-base
```

Answer (score 5):

When you start the R console, it should say across the top

Answer (score 0):

`getRversion()` is probably the cleanest option since it allows you to compare versions:

```r
getRversion()
#> [1] '4.3.1'
getRversion() >= "4.3.0"
#> [1] TRUE
```